# fetching data from mongodb compass to home page

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

I'm currently working on an e-commerce project using Bootstrap. I have encountered a challenge related to fetching data from MongoDB Compass, specifically when data is sent from the product page to the home page.

To provide more context, I have shared the repository for my project on GitHub: https://github.com/YamrajShrestha/e-commerce-bootstrap

I have been facing difficulties in retrieving data from MongoDB Compass and displaying it on the home page. Your expertise in this matter would be immensely valuable to me. If you could spare some time to review the code and documentation and provide insights or suggestions on how to address this specific issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you